# NOT mangle export names?

Tags: webpack-2

[What's new in webpack 2](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7) has this to say about export names:

> ES6 export mangling
>
> In cases where it's possible to track export usage, webpack can mangle export names to single char properties.

I am experimenting with webpack and have started with the very simple "cats" example at http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html

I have converted the js files to ts and tried to enable sourceMaps.
Still when I set a breakpoint in app.ts on

```
console.log(cats);
```

then Chrome stops at the correct place, but I cannot evaluate "cats" in the console (Uncaught reference error: cats is not defined).
If I look into the generated JS, then I find I have to use "r.a" to print the cats.

So: Am I correct that the cause of that is this "export mangling"?

Can it be turned off?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: No, sorry, no answer here.